# Google managed account: privileges needed for API access

Tags: google-api, amazon-iam, privileges, google-account

I am using a Google account managed by my company. I want to activate an API but get the warning that I do not have sufficient privileges. What kind of privileges do you need for API access and where in the admin console do you set it up?

[image: iam error]

Comment: What API do you want to activate?

Comment: Google calendar API